# Materials not showing up on my rig

Tags: materials

Hello everyone i recently have been working on a rig , every time i append the rig into my CYCLES rendered project it is gray ( meaning the rig) the rig seems to not have any materials what so ever. I am a huge noob so if you can please explain in dept because i do not understand some things as i am new to this. Thank You. [image: The pictures shows on how it is originaly supposed to look.As i said before when i render it theres nothing on the rig just grey covering his whole body. I understand that in this picture it is in blender render and in my project im using cycles render , i dont know what to tweak to get it to work]

Answer (score 2):

If you've set up your object materials in the Blender Internal render engine mode, and then switch to Cycles, the materials are not compatible.

You'll have to create new Cycles materials that match your BI (Blender Internal) versions, and apply them to the object instead of the BI versions.